# Python - How to remove/unimport libs was imported before

Tags: python

As we know that, in python 2.x, if we divide two integer values it results in an `int`. However, if using `from __future__ import division`, we instead get a `float` value.

```
>>> 3/2
1
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 3/2
1.5
>>> 
>>> 
>>> 3//2
1
>>> 4/3
1.3333333333333333
>>>
```

So, `//` instead of `/` should be used if we want integers after importing `__future__.division`, but I want to know how to make `/` to return integers again.

Is there any way to un-import or remove the previously imported module?

---

There is a method to unimport libs or Modules in IDLE, that is to **Restart it** by using Ctrl+F6 or Options in Menu

Comment: @NedBatchelder That's exactly my question.

Comment: Please don't post the same question again, @Marslo. If you don't get good answers, try to improve your existing question by adding more detail or clarifying it.

Comment: For what it's worth, you should be using `//` anytime you want integer division.  If you use `/` your code should either be robust enough to handle either integer or true division, or you should be using `__future__` so that you know for certain that you're using true division.

Comment: even after \_\_future\_\_ "modules" are imported, there isn't a way to remove them - even with `del division; from sys import modules; del modules['__future__']`. I think this import overwrites something in the interpreter or something. However, with other standard imports, deleting (though this is risky and should almost never be done) modules can be done by `del`eting `sys.modules[MODULE_NAME]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__future__` looks like a module but isn't really. Importing it actually affects the compilation options of the current module. There's no way to "undo" it, since it effectively happens before the module is even executed.

If it were any other "normal" module, there are ways, but you're out of luck here.
Either deal with the changed semantics, or put the code that needs different compilation in a separate module.

Comment: So, undo the 'normal' module is by using 'del', isn't it?

Comment: Marsalo: No. If you want to change your question I'll answer it, but that won't work in the general case. The module object will stil be referenced by `sys.modules` and by any modules which imported it afterward. `del sys.modules['modulename']` is closer but still incomplete.

Comment: Well, I think 'del' works. I tested by 'Math' module, and it was unimport by ` del math `

Comment: But **sys.modules['math']** doesn't work!! That's strange! the 'math' module do delete from sys.modules. I print them twice, before and after by using 'sys.modules['math'] '.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that `import` makes the sys.modules entry: https://gist.github.com/3751495. Note that this doesn't address the issue of any other references to the module, and as such isn't fully reliable / production worthy.

Comment: I have added my comment. I'm just strange that math module works even if `'math'` is not exists in `sys.modules` anymore.

Answer (score 11):

python has [`reload`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/684171/748858) to re-import an already imported module (which shouldn't be used in production code), but there is no way (that I know) to un-import a module once it's been imported.

Of course, you can just delete the reference to that module in your current namespace:

```
import module
module.foo()
del module
module.foo() #NameError, can't find `module`
```

---

Another point is that `__future__` isn't really a module.  It's more of an instruction to tell the parser how to behave.  As such, when put in a file, it needs to be the first thing in there (before any other imports, etc).  The fact that you can import `__future__` from anywhere in an interactive session is a special case.

Comment: There are ways to unimport modules, e.g. you can just `del` them. It doesn't work for `__future__`, though.

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- No, that removes the reference to the module in the current namespace, which isn't the same thing. -- And it doesn't work if you `from module import *`.

Comment: @LevLevitsky -- You might be able to do something with `sys.modules` to remove it, but that's questionable...

Comment: It kinda works with `from module import *`, you just have to know what names to delete.

Comment: @mgilson: There exists prior art for this. (I'm too lazy to look it up at the moment, sorry.) It gets complicated to do correctly, but it can be done, and made to work well in all cases. It's more correct to say "there's no *officially supported* way".  IIRC the solution involves registering an import hook and figuring out some fiddly back-in-time logic to fix all the references to the module object.

Comment: Yes! **del moudle_name** works for the condition of **import moudle_name**. I still find the way of the condition of **from xxx import xx**, I think I can find them by **print  sys.modules** or **print sys.modules.keys()**

Answer (score 2):

I also have faced this need.

**I don't use `__future__`**.

When I need a float result, I make the divisor a float:

```
>>> 3/float(2)
1.5
```

Comment: "Don't do that." isn't an answer to "How can I?"

Comment: `>>> 3/2.0` 
`1.5`
`>>> 3.0/2`
`1.5` 
`>>> 3.0/2.0` 
`1.5`

Comment: Sorry, I just don't know how to make linebreak in comment box

Comment: @bukzor: you're right, it's not an answer, technically. But I've found many of the you're-doing-it-wrong "answers" on SO to be very useful. Upvote from me.

Answer (score -3):

You can unload it using:

```
>>> del(module)
```

Comment: yes, **del moudle_name** works at some condition, like **import moudle_name**, but it seems cannot work for **from xxx import xxx**.

Comment: This does not unload the module. The object still exists in `sys.modules`, at a minimum.