# Python does not show code changes from imported file

Tags: python, import

I am using a linux python shell and each time I make changes to the imported file I need restart the shell (I tried reimporting the file but the changes were not reflected)

I have a definition in a file called handlers.py

```
def testme():
    print "Hello I am here"
```

I import the file in the python shell

```
>> import handlers as a
>> a.testme()

>>  "Hello I am here"
```

I then change print statement to "Hello I am there", reimport handlers, it does not show the change?

Using Python 2.7 with Mint 17.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to re import an updated package while in Python Interpreter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684171/how-to-re-import-an-updated-package-while-in-python-interpreter)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to explicitly [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imp.html#imp.reload) the module, as in:

```
import lib # first import
# later ....
import imp
imp.reload(lib)  # lib being the module which was imported before
```

note that [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/imp.html) module is pending depreciation in favor of [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html) and in python 3.4 one should use: [`importlib.reload`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload).

Comment: In python 2 the ``reload`` function is a built-in function. No need to import imp, just ``reload(lib)``.

Comment: @Nagasaki45 and perhaps there was some reason that it was removed from python 3. either case it would be much better to go with more cross-platform code.

Answer (score 1):

You should use reload every time you make a change and then import again:

> ```
> reload( handlers )
> import handlers a a
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative answer inside `reload` you can use 
[watchdog](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog/0.5.4) 
 .

A simple program that uses watchdog to monitor directories specified as command-line arguments and logs events generated:

From the website

> **Supported Platforms**
>
> - Linux 2.6 (inotify)
> - Mac OS X (FSEvents, kqueue)
> - FreeBSD/BSD (kqueue)
> - Windows (ReadDirectoryChangesW with I/O completion ports; ReadDirectoryChangesW worker threads)
> - OS-independent (polling the disk for directory snapshots and comparing them periodically; slow and not recommended)