# Run code from other Python file while reflecting changes to other file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

Consider the following Python (2.7.9) code:

**test.py**

```
import test2
import time

while True:
    print test2.getData()
    time.sleep(1)
```

**test2.py**

```
def getData ():
    return [1,2,3]
```

Running with:

```
python -u test.py
```

If I modify *test2.py* while *test.py* is running (say, changing it to `return [4,5,6]`), the output of *test.py* does not change. This is not unexpected.

However, I'd like changes to *test2.py* to be reflected in the output. Is there a way to do this? E.g. something like reparsing *test2.py* every time `test2.getData()` is invoked?

Other things tried, from comments:

- Moving `import test2` into the loop.
- Removing *test2.pyc* while test is running (with `import` in and out of loop).

Comment: I'm assuming your code is converted into byte code before its ran, so modifications to any file are not reflected during execution

Comment: Maybe you could try to move the import statement into the loop, but that still seems strange why you want this

Comment: @cricket_007 test2.pyc is generated, although removing it after modifying test2.py has no effect on the output.

Comment: @cricket_007 The reason I want this is in my real code test2.py is generated by another program, and occasionally regenerated with different data. I could store the data in a text file or database or something and read it every time through the loop, but I'm curious if I can just leave it as Python source because it simplifies my "real" equivalent of test.py a bit.

Comment: Right because test1 only imported test2 once. Before any modification

Comment: @cricket_007 Moving the import into the loop has no effect. Just tested it. It seemed like a good idea, though, ha.

Comment: Hmm. Worth a shot. Anyways - yeah, reading the file might be the only option. Or cache in memory somehow, like Redis or Sqlite memory table

Comment: In the loop you could check to see if the date of the `test2.py` script file is newer than the `test2.pyc` compiled-byte-code file. If it is, you could then re-import the `test2` module which should cause a new `test2.pyc` file it to be automatically re-compiled and used.

Comment: @cricket_007 I finally figured this out; just needed to improve my search keywords. It's [`reload(test2)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/684186/616460). Pretty straightforward. Although too late, since I ended up just storing the data in a CSV file and parsing it (which is pretty easy, too).

Answer (score 1):

If I recall properly, python code will be converted in to a byte code before being executed so there are no ways of changing the code when running it.
What I suggest you do is to create a global variable or a class instead and change that instead. Alternate solution will be to write the data to a file but doesn't benefit much since it needs access to the file system and will not be as fast as variables.