# Changes in python module is not working?

Tags: python, module, anaconda, python-3.6

I have two python files, one is calling (importing) the other. But when I make a change in the module which is called, change is not applied unless I quit from Python and re-open it. Then I can see that changes are working. Here is a short example:

mainfile.py:

```
from otherfile import myfunc
a=5
myfunc(a)
```

otherfile.py:

```
def myfunc (x):
    print(x+3)
```

when I run mainfile.py, it prints 8 as expected. But when I change the last line in otherfile.py to print(x+4), and save it, running mainfile.py still prints 8! After quitting from Python and re-enter it, now it prints 9.

I googled this issue but couldn't find anything. Some people talks about "*init*", I have no idea what it is. I am very new to Python, so I appreciate if you explain this in a very basic way.

Thanks!

Note: I am using Python 3.6.1 on Anaconda 4.4.0 with Spyder 3.1.4

Comment: module-level python code is only re-executed after first-time use if the module is detected as having changed (touching the module - i.e. changing its mod. time - appears to be enough for this to work). Indeed, this makes a lot of sense

Comment: I've found Spyder to do fresh imports every time you run you code, by default. Perhaps delete `.pyc` files after the change.

Comment: a better way is suggested here ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684171/how-to-re-import-an-updated-package-while-in-python-interpreter