# jupyter notebook cannot update module file

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I do not have a code here as this is some general question.

When I modified and saved a py file which was imported in a Jupiter notebook, even I import the module again, I cannot get the updates in the notebook work, what should I do? (I usually shut down the work, but it is apparently inefficient)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`importlib` should still work. Quoting from a [similar solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684171/how-to-re-import-an-updated-package-while-in-python-interpreter) but concerning the interpreter:

Python3 >= 3.4: `importlib.reload(packagename)`

Python3 < 3.4: `imp.reload(packagename)`